# How to correctly use the cassandra.config startup parameter

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to start up a Cassandra instance through the command line and am having some trouble setting the cassandra.config parameter:

```
cassandra -f -Dcassandra.config=path/to/config
```

When I set it to the path where my config files are, the process halts and throws the following error:

```
ERROR 02:11:31 Fatal configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate /path/to/config
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.getStorageConfigURL(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:64) ~[main/:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:75) ~[main/:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:136) ~[main/:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:112) ~[main/:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:155) [main/:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:410) [main/:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:453) [main/:na]
Cannot locate /path/to/config
```

I know the directory exists, so I'm not really sure to go from here. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: I read on a couple of other forums that the documentation is incorrect and that the config path should actually point to the Cassandra YAML file. I tried this as well which resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some errors in your config on the layout. There has to be a certain layout for a config to work. Can you provide the config?

Answer (score 0):

file:///path/to/config should work as YamlConfigurationLoader expects path to be URL.